# I decided to add a photo using background-image, but when I decided to add no-repeat or center, the photo just disappears what is the problem

Tags: html, css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Main { height: 800px; background-image: url('../img/bg/laptop.png'); }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, it's difficult to help you with what little information you've provided. Please consider reading [ask] and updating your question with a [mre] of your code so we can better assist you :)

Comment: My guess is you are adding them to the background image rather than separately or putting all of them in a background. But impossible to be sure without seeing your code. And have you checked what CSS is being applied using your browser dev tools inspect facility?